# How do I make a Dynamic table that structures itself with what I have in the database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make it so that when I get the Units from the database if they are the same unit to combine the cells and after the end of the combination of the cells one cell under and two cell to the right to do an increment (UI, UII, UIII, UIV, UV) cell.

My database:

Name: gradebook

Table name: Evidence

IdEvidence (int)(auto Increment)

id_class   (int)(fk)

evaluation (varchar)

unit       (varchar)

percentage (int)

dueDate    (date)

this is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('Evidence');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Unit1</td>
    <td>Unit1</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Unit2</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Unit3</td>
    <td>Unit3</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Unit4</td>
    <td>Unit4</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>EDi</td>
    <td>ED1</td>
    <td>EC1</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>UI</td>
    <td>EP1</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>UII</td>
    <td>EC2</td>
    <td>EP2</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>UIII</td>
    <td>EP3</td>
    <td>ED2</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Due Date</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: foreach http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-template-flexy.attribute.foreach.php

Comment: I am not understanding your run-on sentence. "if they are the same unit to combine the cells and after the end of the combination of the cells" and "do an increment (UI, UII, UIII, UIV, UV) cell". Can you clarify?

Comment: yes if they are the same unit to combine the cells and after the combination, one cell under and two cells to the right to do an increment cell it could be UI,UII,UIII... or just plain numbers 1,2,3... hope this clarifies